# Map stopped showing - Google MAP v3 API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a web page displaying a map with 2 custom markers. The page worked fine until today. I'm guessing google made some updates on the API or something similar. heres the code:

```
<head>
<link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body { padding:0; margin:0; }

table#details td
{
    text-align:center;
        font-size:18px;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #85c7d7 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #85c7d7 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #85c7d7 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #85c7d7));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #85c7d7 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #85c7d7 100%);
    background-color:#FFF;
        border-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius:15px; /* Old Firefox */
}
table#details
{
    background-image:url(images/backtable.jpg);
    background-image:();
        width:680px;
}

body {
    font-family: Calibri,"Gill Sans","Gill Sans MT","Myriad Pro",Myriad,Frutiger,"Frutiger Linotype",Univers,"DejaVu Sans Condensed","Liberation Sans","Nimbus Sans L",Tahoma,Geneva,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

input
{
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
}
select
{
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
}
#map-canvas {
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
        margin:20px;
        float:left;
      }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

</head>
<body>


        <table id="details">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <div id="map-canvas1" style="margin:15px;width:300px; height:220px; float:left;"></div>
            </td><td width=380>
            <h3 style="color:#F00;">Une clinique a besoin de vous!</h3>
            <img src="images/intercom.png" style="margin-top:-15px;"><br/>

        de <b>8h</b> &agrave; <b>18h</b><br/><span style="text-transform:uppercase">Clinique Du ruisseau de la bonne etoile <br/>4885 Henri-Bourassa  ville Montreal<br/>
</span>
<img src="images/accepteoffre.png" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:10px;" onClick="document.location= 'insertwishdispo.aspx?Seq=3087&Midi=1&Tel=5146298488&HeureDebut=8&HeureFin=18&SeqH=1010&SeqC=7&Jour=9&Annee=2014&Mois=4&Courriel=thomasdc7@hotmail.com&MotDePasse=alloallo'"/>

<br/><span style="cursor:pointer;font-size:12px;" onClick="document.location = 'add_hd.aspx?Annee=2014&Mois=4&Jour=9&Seq=1010&Courriel=thomasdc7@hotmail.com&MotDePasse=alloallo';"><u>Je d&eacute;cline mais je veux cr&eacute;er une autre disponibilit&eacute;</u></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

 <script>

function initialize() {




 var Center=new google.maps.LatLng(18.210885,-67.140884);
    var directionsDisplay1;
    var directionsService1 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var properties1 = {
    suppressMarkers: true
};


  directionsDisplay1 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(properties1);


  //latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.522699, -73.7068679)
  latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.522699, -73.7068679)
  var mapOptions1 = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  };

  var map1;
  map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas1'),
      mapOptions1);
    directionsDisplay1.setMap(map1);
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      title:"Clinique",
      visible: true,
      icon: 'images/toothmap.png'
  });

    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.5196215, -73.7337152)

    var markerMe1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      title:"Moi",
      visible: true,
      icon: 'images/avatars_map.png'
  });
  marker1.setMap(map1);
  markerMe1.setMap(map1);


var start1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.522699, -73.7068679)
var end1 =  new google.maps.LatLng(45.5196215, -73.7337152)
var request1 = {
origin:start1,
destination:end1,
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
 };

 directionsService1.route(request1, function(result, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay1.setDirections(result);
}
});





}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
loadScript();

</script>

</body>
```

The page is generated with a aspx loop so that's why objects are named objectname'1',

The interesting part is it worked recently with no change, meaning it must be something about an update or code that is not tolerated anymore.

Comment: You are including the API twice, when I remove the copy in the head (and change it to the release version, v=3), a local version works.

Comment: Sorry I didn't visit back sooner. This was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working.. http://jsfiddle.net/baL75/1/
I had to make a few changes:

on the markers image URL

```
icon: 'http://lorempixel.com/40/20/'
```

also in the context of initialize.

```
initialize = function() {
```

But that's all.. there is no API changes that would make your code not work.

Comment: to me the double include of the API was the problem, and it only stopped working recently. meaning google probably did make a change preventing this idiotic move on my part ;)

Thanks Enapupe!